# When to use Datadog Distribution and Histogram

Tags: histogram, distribution, datadog

I cannot find any article that describes the advantages of using datadog histogram compared to datadog distribution for apps that run on multi instance. Would someone kindly help me on deciding the best choice between those two?

Answer (score 4):

One of the main differences that I found in the DataDog documentation:

- The **HISTOGRAM** metric submission type represents the statistical distribution of a set of values **calculated Agent-side in one time interval**. The Agent aggregates the values that are sent in a defined time interval and produces different metrics which represent the set of values.
- The **DISTRIBUTION** metric submission type represents the global statistical distribution of a set of values calculated across your entire distributed infrastructure in one time interval. A DISTRIBUTION metric sends all the raw data during a time interval to Datadog. Aggregations occur on the server-side. Because the underlying data structure represents raw, unaggregated data, distributions provide two major features: Calculation of percentile aggregations and Customization of tagging

https://docs.datadoghq.com/metrics/types/

https://docs.datadoghq.com/metrics/distributions/

Answer (score 1):

Distributions provide enhanced query functionality and configuration options compared to histograms. Since aggregation happens at server-side for distribution styled metrics, you can calculate globally accurate percentiles for your services.

Histograms on the other hand, are aggregated on the agent side. So even if you see a .p99 time series in datadog, it will be per host. You can aggregate it in datadog by taking an average, but it won't be a true p99.

One use case that distribution helps solve is defining your service's SLOs.